# reverse ssh using systemd-cron is not connecting

Tags: ssh, cron, systemd, arch-linux

I have a script that checks my home rpi2 for a file using ssh, pk auth, if the file exists it deletes it (again ssh pk auth) and opens a reverse ssh with:
`ssh -fN -R xxxx:localhost:22 user@myhomepiserver.com`

when running the script from the command line it works well i get the reverse shell.

When running from systemd-cron, i don't get the process up!
checking with `ps -efwww|grep "ssh -f"|grep -v grep`

the crontab is simply:
`*/1 * * * * /home/me/my_r_ssh_script.sh`

I verified that:

1. happens on both arch arm and arch x86 with systemd-cron installed.
2. does not happen on ubuntu with crontab installed.

BTW, i have verified that the script runs as use 'me' and indeed it does do i'm sure it uses the right key, also i tried logging  g with -vvv and what i saw was that unlike from command line seems like the remote does not answer when i run from cron OR maybe the answer doesn't get to the client for some reason, not sure why.

Any help\hint is appreciated!

Comment: seems like systemd kills every process created by the cron scripts from some reason.

Comment: put on hold ? this is an office solution for managing my iot usb hub in the office to work from home, don't be quick to judge :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[systemd-cron](https://github.com/systemd-cron/systemd-cron) is not an official systemd package. It does not seem to offer any detailed configuration of the executed systemd units, so I recommend configuring the timers yourself, see for example https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers#As_a_cron_replacement .

Then you can play with the following options: [KillMode](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html), [Type, RemainAfterExit, PIDFile](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), .. to prevent the process from being killed.

Comment: 1. wanted to save me the hassle of creating my own timed service
2. changing the code in systemd-cron to be KillMode=process is actually a good idea as it will behave like normal crontab does. didn't know about that option.
3. the document apprently offers a solution i couldn't see till i looked for it. i'll still accept this answer as it's  more creative and can contain a real solution to systemd-cron

Comment: solution i've found:
* drop the systemd-cron and use real cron client.
* don't run ssh is the background with '-f' this way the process says a live just like normal systemd process, issue is, i don't have anyone to kill it except issusing a kill on the remote myself.

Comment: @codeScriber thanks for your feedback. I wondered why the ssh client would be forking but I couldn't ask this due to not enough points to post comments and asking questions in an answer being against the site policy :) (I also noticed only now you actually included the -f in the ps command you posted in your question) Stil, I'm glad my answer managed to help you find a solution!